# Moving xampp breaks php gallery

Tags: php, xampp

After moving xampp's root directory to a different folder, I've started getting an error saying stuff can't be found. The error messages seem to be pointing to the old directory however.

Edit:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('gallery_full.php?i=2016mac_03.jpg','_gallery','');return false;"><img class="img-responsive" src="/images/gallery/2016mac/2016mac_31_t.jpg"></a>

<p style="margin-top:10px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('gallery_full.php?i=2016mac_03.jpg','_gallery','');return false;">2016 Bird Translocation</a></p>
```

Basically all the paths are relative so unless I'm missing something, the js call falls back on the old link.

Comment: So correct the path for those stuff??

Comment: Good question, I decided to edit main post for this.